# JQuery Restrict the difference between two datepickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers

```
  $(function() {
    $('#DateFrom').datepicker({ onSelect: showUser, minDate: -90, maxDate: "+1D" });
  });

  $(function() {
    $('#DateTo').datepicker({ onSelect: showUser, minDate: -90, maxDate: "+1D" });
  });
```

and these are the 2 html inputs for the date pickers

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="DateFrom" id="DateFrom" /> 

<input type="text" class="datepicker"  name="DateTo" id="DateTo"  />
```

I need to restrict the number of days that a user can choose based on the datefrom selection. I want to be able to restrict it to 7 days.

So if a user selects 1/1/14, then they should only be able to select up to 1/7/14, so any date from the 1/1/14 to 1/7/14.

I guess the theory is to use the onselect of the `DateTo` and check what the `DateFrom` selection is, then change the `maxDate` to be 7 days from the `DateFrom` selection.

I get the general idea, and i know how to select the already selected date:

```
var StartDate = $( "#DateFrom" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
```

but thats about all i can decypher.

the onselect for both datepickers calls:

```
function showUser() {
    // Retrieve values from the selects
    var DateFrom = document.getElementById('DateFrom').value;
    var DateTo = document.getElementById('DateTo').value;
    var StartDate = $( "#DateFrom" ).datepicker( "getDate" );

    if (DateFrom=="" || DateTo == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","StreetHailDrivers.php?DateFrom="+DateFrom+"&DateTo="+DateTo,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Could i put the datepicker maxDate limit in that?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this?

Comment: I did, but id rather get downvoted and given somewhere to look, than not ask the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
$(function () {
    $('#DateFrom').datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            var date = $('#DateFrom').datepicker('getDate');
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000*60*60*24*6));
            $('#DateTo').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
            $('#DateTo').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#DateFrom').datepicker('getDate'));
            showUser();
        },
        minDate: -90, 
        maxDate: "+1D"
    });

    $('#DateTo').datepicker({
        onSelect: showUser,
        minDate: -90, 
        maxDate: "+1D"
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3rU42/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate suggestion:

If you are restricting the day they can pick in the "TO" datepicker to only 1 day, then why have a second datepicker at all?  Just calculate 7 days from the FROM datepicker date and display it as text.  Silly to make the user pick a date when theres only one option.

Comment: pretty sure he meant to say that they can only choose a date that is 7 days or later

Answer (score 0):

A little suggestion, try finding a JQuery Range Picker. They'll include some of these tedious functionality for you already. Going on google and searching just that gives you a ton of choices.

etc..https://github.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker

Back to the question though, you could put a callback function on 'onClose' in 'DateFrom' so that whenever the date is change, you will change the 'minDate' on 'DateTo' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `beforeShow` parameter to modify the `minDate` of the `To` field, and then simply use date objects and a `+7` to select a date one week from the `From` date:

```
$("#to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",  // set the default to 1 week from today

    beforeShow: function () {
        var date = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');  // From date
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);             // 7 days after From date
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", date );  // set minDate to from+7
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/aHBc3/)