# How to restrict years range in date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, date-format

I am using following script for datepicker.
Currently I am restricting the maximum year by mentioning 'YearRange:2014:2015'. This looks like a manual work. But I want a code which can automatically set 1 year from today.

```
$<script>
  $(function() {

    $( "#checkin" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+2d",
      yearRange: '2014:2015',
      changeMonth: true,dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate: 1,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#checkout" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });

    $( "#checkout" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+3d",dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      yearRange: '2014:2015',
                minDate: 2,
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#checkin" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });

  }); 
  </script>
```

Comment: Try and be more specific, what exactly are you trying to do? The yearRange options only restricts the years shown in the dropdown that is visible when selecting years are enabled ?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Comment: Dear Adeneo,

Let me explain you with example.
If a guest doing hotel reservation on today(06/05/2014) means, In check-in and Check-out date selection, the date picker should allow the guest to select the date between 06-05-2014 than 06-05-2015(1yr) only.

Got my point?

Comment: @Shah - I think I do, you're trying to restrict the datepickers, like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126837/jquery-restrict-the-difference-between-two-datepickers

Answer (score 4):

```
var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(year, 0, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(year+1, 11, 31)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To set the max date that can be selected, you can use the `maxDate` option

```
maxDate: '+1y' // one year from today
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PazPx/1/)

This would also limit the yearRange when `showYear` is set to true.

Comment: Thanks adeneo,

Simply the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

```
yearRange: '1950:2013', // specifying a hard coded year range
```

or this way

```
yearRange: "-100:+0", // last hundred years
```

Comment: this only affects the dropdown option, and doesn't actually restrict the user from choosing certain days/years