# jQuery datepicker disable end date value

Tags: php, jquery, html

Refer to this image:
[image]

In my company table, I have 3 fields:
- ID (int auto_increment)
- start_date (date)
- end date (date)

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(selected){
            $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option","minDate",selected);
        }
    });

    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(selected){
            $("#datepikcer1").datepicker("option","maxDate",selected);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//db connection

$q = "select * from company where ID = '".$_GET['ID']."'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<tr>
    <td>Start Date : </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="exhstartdate" id="datepicker1" value="<?php if($row['start_date'] == NULL) echo ''; else echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['start_date'])); ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>End Date : </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="exhenddate" id="datepicker2" value="<?php if($row['end_date'] == NULL) echo ''; else echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['end_date'])); ?>" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My requirement is end date cannot greater than start date.
How should I disable the end date value when the end date value is greater than the start date value from the database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126837/jquery-restrict-the-difference-between-two-datepickers

Comment: I tried your script and it works just fine. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2j4p808f/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setEndDatePicker(); //set end date picker based on start date
    });

    var startDate = $("#datepicker1").val(); //get start date value and split to year, month and day
    var sDate = startDate.split("-");
    var day = sDate[0];
    var month = parseInt(sDate[1]) - 1;
    var year = sDate[2];

    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

    // set again the minDate for end datepicker when start date changes
    $("#datepicker1").change(function(){
         startDate = $("#datepicker1").val(); //get new start date value
         sDate = startDate.split("-");
         day = sDate[0];
         month = parseInt(sDate[1]) - 1;
         year = sDate[2]; 

         setEndDatePicker(); //reset the minDate for end datepicker
    });

    function setEndDatePicker(){
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
            minDate: new Date(year, month, day), //use dynamically initialized minDate
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    }
</script>
```